# How to exclude a package under a src folder in Maven?

Tags: maven

My progect folder's structure is

```
project_root
| src
    | localstore
    | main
```

How to exclude `localstore` package form generated jar?
I used this pom file and anyway there is a localstore folder within a exported jar file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SomeProjectName</groupId>
    <artifactId>SomeProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies> ... </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <!--this doesn't work-->
                    <excludePackageNames>**/localstore/**</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you have such directory? What is contained there? And why is it part of the project? Apart from that by default the directory will never being part of the resulting jar file except you have configured things different... Please show your full pom file.

Comment: @khmarbaise That folder (actuly a package) used for test purposes and any classes from that package are not used (and should not used) in production. Thats why I want to exclude it. Now it's just under `src` in eclipse structure. I added in the topic pom file if it can help in some way.

Comment: Usually you have your sources in `src/main/java` and your tests in `src/test/java`. Then you don't need to configure anything.

Comment: As @JFabianMeier already stated Tests/test classes should be located in `src/test/java` or resources for test should be in `src/test/resources` will make life easier. Convention over configuration....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, to exclude the whole `localstore` packade under src folder we need use this in the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>localstore/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

And if the goal to exclude only *.java sources, we should use `localstore/*.java` there.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want this special structure instead of the standard one.

Comment: @JFabianMeier maybe that's an option (I've tried that and it works), but not quite in the context of my question.

Comment: As khmarbaise said: Following standards is usually a good idea.